# How can I do to create a link to the source for an image?

Tags: captions

I am trying to show an image using LaTeX and also to show the source but I don't achieve.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure} [ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]myimage.jpg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \captionsource{Caption}{\ref{https://www.myimage.jpg}}{test}
  \label{fig:gliederung}
\end{figure}
```

But below the image I got that : `Caption??test`

How can I do to solve that?

Comment: `\ref` is a command to refer to an internal marked in your document created with `\label`. To print a `\url`, go with `\url{https://www.myimage.jpg}`. (Note sure if that helps. I don't know how your `\captionsource` is defined.)

Comment: thank you but in your solution I see the link I want a word when I click on it I go to the website of the picture. Thank you

Comment: Then use `\href{https://www.myimage.jpg}{Linked words}` (but again, I have to guess what would make sense, since we don't know the definition of `\captionsource` and which packages you have loaded).

Comment: Normally you would include the source information into the caption it self. This is the easiest to do and what we see in most books.